# Database access using docker

Tags: docker

I installed a new wordpress project using docker's guide:

```
mkdir my-wordpress-site
cd my-wordpress-site
ddev config --project-type=php
ddev composer create wordpress/skeleton --no-interaction --prefer-dist
ddev config --docroot=wp --project-type=wordpress
ddev restart
```

All done and I ran the front-end configuration.

I am used to running things in windows(xampp) and heard of MAMP for mac. but now I need to use docker and have no clue of how to go about things.

Question is: Is there a way I can access my database using Docker? ssh or anything?

Answer (score 5):

There are ever-so-many ways to access the database. `ddev describe` will open your eyes to them.

- As @Andy Mardell points out, you can use the built-in PHPMyAdmin (link in `ddev describe`)
- You can also use a mysql client on the host, the port and such for this are also shown in `ddev describe`
- You can also use `ddev mysql` for direct access to the database (ddev v1.10+)
- On macOS, you can use `ddev sequelpro` if you have the excellent, free SequelPro installed.
- You can also ssh into either the web container or the db container, `ddev ssh` or `ddev ssh -s db` and use the mysql client there.
- You can also use `ddev exec mysql`, which is really pretty much the same as `ddev mysql`

I hope that's enough ways! :)

Answer (score 4):

### PhpMyAdmin

phpMyAdmin is installed with the commands you ran.

It seems to generate a random port. So do the following:

`docker ps`

You should see a line which is called `drud/phpmyadmin`. Look along the table and you should see the port it's running on. In my case, this was `0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp`

So if I go to http://localhost:32773 I see phpmyadmin, where you can access and edit your database.

PhpMyAdmin is fine to start, but you might want to use a database client to remotely access the database long term:

### Remote access

If you want to use a database client to connect to your database, there is a similar process. Find out what port your database image is exposing:

`ps docker`

See the line called `drud/ddev-dbserver`? What port is this using? In my case it was `127.0.0.1:32782->3306/tcp`.

So to connect to this database I can use port 32782. Again, in my case the details to connect were:

Host: 127.0.0.1
Database: db
User: db
Password: db
Port: 32782

Hope that helps